# in the v3 api, how can i list the most recent items?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My app needs to sync up with the youtube api to pull in info about any new videos. But in the PlaylistItems.list docs, I don't see any kind of "sort order" or date filtering parameters.

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to download all the playlist items every time I want to check if there is a new video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to download the playlist your self and then sort them locally.    As you have already seen there is no way to sort them or filter the number of rows.

I think there is a really old feature request for the ability to sort. [Playlist API: Add support for sorting playlist items response](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6869&q=sort&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)

What I find interesting is that they still haven't done more then set the status to "Acknowledged" and it took them two years to do that.

I guess this goes back to the question I always have who's responsibility is it to sort the data?   The API or the developer?  It appears that Google thinks its the developer.

Comment: it does seem strange, adding this feature seems easy enough and would reduce the number of api calls developers would need to make.

Answer (score 1):

I found a post on my travels that said that all play lists generated are ordered from newest first to oldest. Excepting personal playlists that the user creates which are ordered as they were added. So first added will be first in list. So [0] node is first in list response.

On the other hand, you can use the [publishedAt] property to get a time stamp.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=.........  

[snippet] => Array ([publishedAt]=> 2010-05-12T23:57:34.000Z
```

Or

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=........
```

However please note, this call will give **EVERYTHING** from the channel. Video uploads **and** playlists created.

As there are many call possibilities in the api, I am sure that you can find the right one that works for your needs.

Comment: thanks, i should have mentioned i am using the playlistItems api call. it's not sorted for sure, i've had bugs reported about missing items and confirmed the order returned by the api is not the same as the website.

Comment: playlistitems also has [snippet] => [publishedAt]=> . So it should work for you.